# How to compress C++ vector of unsigned chars for quick comparisons? No decompression needed

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, compression

I have a lot of vectors of unsigned chars that will be frequently compared to new vectors. Each vector has about 100 elements. To avoid comparing all 100 elements, I'd like to compress each vector to some value. Any integral data type is fine. I do not ever need to decompress this number. Is there a quick compression I can use for this?

Comment: You mean like a hash function?

Comment: And how many vectors do you have, and how many times are you going to compare them? Have you tried using an `unordered_map` (which uses a hash function to compare the entries)?

Comment: You could try using memcmp to compare the binary representations of the vectors, but there is no guarantee that there will not be some padding or other difference between identical vectors (Idt).

Comment: I wouldn't think that comparing 100 elements is costly. You have to consider whether compressing the vector would take longer than just comparing it.

Comment: @hacatu Why wouldn't the compiler implement the comparison using memcmp if that's the most efficient way?

Comment: You can xor the values to get a simple hash. Please do look up [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). Remember to **MEASURE** whether this helps, and remember that when two hashes compare as equal you still have to compare the full arrays if you need to be sure.

Comment: @Neil Kirk You are right, I was thinking if the OP cared about ordering comparison, but I guess that was never said.

Comment: When you say "comparison", you mean "equality".  You don't care about less than or greater than, correct?

Comment: @franji1: Correct, I only care about equality.

Comment: I don't know anything about hashes. I will look into them.

Comment: hash (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hash) is illegal in most states in the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash function instead of compression.  Generate a small hash, e.g. 32 bits, from the 100 elements of each vector.  Then when you get a new vector, compare the hash of the new vector with the hashes of all of your old vectors.  If the hashes are not equal, then the vectors are not equal.  If the hashes *are* equal, then the vector *may or may not* be equal.  In that case, compare the entire 100 elements of the two vectors to see if they really are equal.  It will be rare to get a false positive, i.e. a case where the hashes are equal but the vectors are not.  Therefore you will invest in a full 100-element comparison almost always only when there is match.